# Resize PDF View when device orientation changes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pdfkit

I have a ViewController in my app that allows the user to open a PDF. The app supports landscape and portrait orientation the of device. I am having a problem when the user changes the devices orientation after opening the PDF. The PDF has two pages:
Page 1 - All pink and
Page 2 - All purple

I am encountering a framing problem once the PDF is opened and the user changes the devices orientation. If the PDF is opened in a portrait orientation, the pdf only fills up half of the screen once the ordination of the device is changed to landscape:
[image: Portrait Orientation after being opened in a portrait orientation]
[image: Landscape Orientation after being opened in portrait orientation]

Likewise, if the PDF is opened in a Landscape orientation, the pdf will only show on half of the screen once the orientation of the device is portrait:
[image: Lanscape Orientation after being opened in a landscape Orientation]
[image: Portrait Orientation after being opened in a landscape Orientation]

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class PDFfun: UIViewController {

    var pdfView = PDFView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.frame)

    if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Blank", withExtension: "pdf"),
        let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL),
        let _ = document.page(at: 0) {

        pdfView.document = document
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        pdfView.autoScales = true

     }
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("landscape")
            pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.frame)
            pdfView.autoScales = true
        } else {
            print("portait")
            pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.frame)
            pdfView.autoScales = true
        }
    }
}
```

I tired adding `override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` fix my problem but I notice no change.

Comment: Why not just use constraints?

Comment: in your viewWillTransition method do: pdfView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height). But you should definitly use layoutConstraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is you add layout constraints to your pdfView. In your viewDidLoad for example:

```
   pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.addSubview(pdfView)     
   view.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pdfView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pdfView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pdfView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pdfView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ])
```

If your dont want to use layoutConstraint you also can set the frame for your pdfView in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

         pdfView.frame = view.frame
    }
```

And dont forget to remove your code inside the viewWillTransition method.

Comment: I added your code to my 'ViewDidLoad()' and I received this error upon trying to open the PDF document "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000066f9d0 PDFView:0x7fee2fc35e30.leading == UIView:0x7fee2fc2d5f0.leading   (inactive)>
 When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug."

Comment: @voodoo make sure the pdfView is subview of the viewcontrollers view. i edited the code with the addSubview method.